# Replace windows default DirectX SDK path with our own path in C++

Tags: c++, windows, directx

Sorry for asking silly question but I'm stuck with it. I have installed the DirectX SDK for June 2010 and right now when I create a new project in VC++ it'll use the inherited settings in VC++ Directories and in these inherited paths, default DirectX SDK from windows is laid down! I added path of mine however it's still using the Windows's SDK. How can I change this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found these instructions for changing the path 
http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=15817

Comment: This is just setting up the IDE. I need to replace Windows's default DirectX SDK path with my own.